# an open subspace of a complete metric space

Tags: general-topology

I came across this problem:
Suppose $Y$ is an open subspace of  a complete metric space $(X,d)$.

Prove that $Y$ is completely metrizable.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Perhaps you can 'approximate' $Y$ from the 'inside' with closed sets?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The idea is to stretch distances close to the boundary of $Y$, so that sequences in $Y$ that converge to points outside $Y$ are no longer Cauchy. Without loss of generality assume that $d$ is bounded. Define

$$f:Y\to\Bbb R:y\mapsto\frac1{d(y,X\setminus Y)}\;,$$

and consider the function

$$\rho:Y\times Y\to\Bbb R:\langle y,z\rangle\mapsto d(y,z)+|f(y)-f(z)|\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

If the Cauchy sequence in Y converges to a point in the subspace Y by the metric d, then the added term from the HINT above for the Y metric is as small as one pleases and $\rho$ approaches d.  When the Cauchy sequence in Y converges by d to a boundary point of Y, the added term does not converge and the sequence by the $\rho$ metric is not Cauchy.  Thus the only sequences that are Cauchy in (Y,$\rho$) are those that  converge in Y by the d metric, to which the $\rho$ metric converges.